# Android Beginners Import error

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android app using a tutorial, but I have an error at

```
           import org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream;
```

ERROR:

```
           import org.apache.commons.fileupload can't be resolved
```

I don't understand how to import this. Is there any jar file in need with my eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need the Apache Commons FileUpload jar. Get it [here](http://www.fightrice.com/mirrors/apache//commons/fileupload/binaries/commons-fileupload-1.2.2-bin.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the Apache Commons FileUpload jar:
http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

You should create a folder named `libs` in the same level as `src`, then just right click on the file `Build Path--> Add to Build Path`.